# Firebase array order by date(timestamp) - Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have array of songs in Firebase server.
Every song has `lastCommentAt` property which is timestamp.

I want to retrieve the songs order by the closest `lastCommentAt` time to the current time.

This is my Firebase rules:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth != null",
        "songs": {
          ".indexOn": ["lastCommentAt"]
        }
    }
}
```

[Songs feed example - CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNWojK)

I can't use **orderByChild()**. It making weird problem:

- Uncorrect order
- loadMore() is loading the same 2 songs in loop. It means unlimited
  songs list.

[Songs feed with orderByChild() example - CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doEVbG)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the root cause of your issue is a lack of understanding of the effect of `startAt()` when used in conjunction with `orderByChild()`. For more info read the [Firebase documentation on queries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries).

If using `orderByChild("lastCommentAt")` then the `startAt()` function applies **not** to the ID of the instance but to the `lastCommentAt` property of each instance.

So once you've added `orderByChild("lastCommentAt")` then the `startAt()` needs have the first parameter as the first `lastCommentAt` value you want to get and the second parameter is the last `lastCommentAt` value you want to get.